# “To” or not after the verb “to be”

Tags: grammar, infinitives

Considering the two sentences:

> The first thing they would do was take money
>
> The first thing they would do was to take money

Which one is grammatically more correct?
There is a rule which says when to use “to” after the verb to be?
Thanks

Comment: I like the first version better, but I think this is more of a stylistic choice than a grammatical one.